# geometric intersection number 0 and essential closed curve

Tags: geometric-topology

I'd like to prove the following proposition.

"If Σ is an orientable surface and $y$ is a closed curve on Σ such that $i(x, y) =
0$ for every simple closed curve $x$. Then $y$ is either homotopically trivial or homotopic to
a boundary curve or homotopic to a puncture."

where $i(x, y)$ is geometric intersection number of $x$ and $y$

$i.e.$ $i(x, y)$ is min{#$x$ $\cap$ $y$|$x\in[x]$,$y\in[y]$} ($[x]$ is free homotopy class of $x$ )

I have an idea which is "If $y$ is essential closed curve, then there is some loop $y'$ such that $i(y, y') >0$"

But I still can't prove it.
Please give me some advice.